# Does Cordova support WebGL on IOS

Tags: cordova, webgl

I am now using Cordova to port my HTML5/WebGL application to iOS device.
However I have trouble enabling the WebGL working on iOS device.
Does anybody know how WebGL is supported by Cordova? It would be very helpful if you can share a simple sample to do that.

Comment: http://atnan.com/blog/2011/11/03/enabling-and-using-webgl-on-ios/

Answer (score 0):

IOS8 will provide WebGL in mobile Safari and to the webview used by Cordova.  Who knows if it'll be worth anything - but at least it's coming.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, WebGL is only supported only on iOS8 and further, if you build a webGL app with Cordova then it will work on iOS8 device. You can use [PhoneGap build](http://build.phonegap.com) or [IntelXDK](http://xdk.intel.com) to build the Cordova app

I just confirmed that it does work on iOS8, nothing special needed, just build with Cordova and install on iOS8 device.